# Start with clean database

Tags: database, setup-script, table

When I want to start over with a clean database in a local/dev environment, is it enough to delete all tables and let the setup/update/data scripts (Mage, custom modules, own modules...) build up everything again?

Would you end up with a ready to go database or will I miss some important table data?

I gave it a try and at first it seems to go well, but I just wanted to double check...

Answer (score 3):

Try the `--cleanup-database` in magento command line tool. [Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html)

Answer (score 1):

deleting all the tables and the cache should be enough.
But keep in mind that you will lose EVERYTHING.
It would be just like installing magento again because basically that will happen.

Comment: tnx for the confirmation. I'm well aware of the fact that I would lose everything ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be enough to delete the database. Note, that you also lose all configuration made in the admin panel, including static blocks, cms pages, payment and shipping methods configurations. Generally, it will be better to create backup before this.